# I use camera and storage read/write in my android app then privacy policy needed?

Tags: android, camera, privacy-policy

In my android application I use camera access and also use storage read/write then privacy policy needed for publish my android app? And also if I got warning to add privacy policy then what I have to do?

Comment: do you manifest permission?

Comment: Yes I do @ZeroOne

Comment: Hey there, yes you need a privacy policy for camera access/storage read/write. The sensitive permissions are a data collection practice that gets flagged by Google and therefore consequently need a privacy policy. You have to disclose your use of the two permissions and state the purpose of these permissions in your app. [This post](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/) will help you getting that done. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **you need a Privacy Policy** because camera is a [sensitive permission](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/personal-sensitive/) that triggers the requirement of having a Privacy Policy.

Other sensitive permissions that you may request from your manifest group file can include: record audio, read phone state, get accounts, read contacts

**What you can do is:**

- If you do not need camera access, update the manifest group file and remove asking for this permission
- If you need camera access, update your app listing page by adding a Privacy Policy.

**How to update your listing page:**

1. Log into your Google Play Developer Console
2. Select "All Applications"
3. Select your app
4. Click "Store Listing"
5. Enter the public URL of your Privacy Policy at the "Privacy Policy" field:

[image: Privacy Policy field URL from Google Play Store via TermsFeed]

**Where to host your Privacy Policy**

You must host the agreement yourself as Google won't host it for you. If you don't have a website for your app, other free options are:

- [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com)
- [A Medium blog page](https://medium.com)
- Pastebin, Google Sites etc.

You can look into [TermsFeed](https://termsfeed.com/privacy-policy/generator/), but full disclosure: this is our tool to create and host a Privacy Policy for Google Play Store apps.